# How to Pass data from UICollectionViewCell(inside UITableviewCell) to another UIViewcontroller Swift3

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView which is inside UITableViewCell. I have 7 button in UICollectionViewCell. When i press Button1, the data should be pass to Another Viewcontroller, But it Doesn't.

// TableviewCell

```
import UIKit


class backgroundViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var dayName : String!
var audioFileURL : String!
 var tittle : String?

// guided collectionView
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!


let data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]

let images = ["circleblank","circleblank","circleblank","circleblank","circleblank","circleblank","circleblank"]

@IBOutlet var Labeltittle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var LabelDetail: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var iconview: UIImageView!

 extension backgroundViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell1", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.Label.text = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])

    let bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    var imageView : UIImageView
   imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x :4.1,y : 3.9, width:        cell.ImageView.frame.size.width, height : cell.ImageView.frame.size.height));
    imageView.image = UIImage(named : "blankoval")


    bgColorView.addSubview(imageView)


    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Collection view at row \(collectionView.tag) selected index path \(indexPath.row)")
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:

        dayName = "Day 1"

       self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day1
        break
    case 1:
    self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day2
        dayName = "Day 2"

        break
    case 2:
    self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day3
        dayName = "Day 3"

        break
    case 3:
    self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day4
        dayName = "Day 4"

        break
    case 4:

       self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day5
        dayName = "Day 5"

        break
    case 5:
      self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day6
        dayName = "Day 6"

        break
    default:
        self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day7
        dayName = "Day 7"
        break

    }

 }

}
}
```

// TableViewController

```
import UIKit

class PlayerGuidedTableViewController: UITableViewController {


var audioFileURL : String!
var dayName : String!




// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 600
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> backgroundViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guidedPlayerCell") as! backgroundViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayerGuidedTableViewController.playPauseButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)


    return cell
}



 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MainPlayer" {
        if let collectionCell: backgroundViewCell = sender as? backgroundViewCell {
            if let collectionView: UICollectionView = collectionCell.superview as? UICollectionView {
                if let playerVC = segue.destination as? playerGuidedViewController {


                    playerVC.Day = dayName
                    playerVC.UrlAudio = audioFileURL
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)    {
//        if segue.identifier == "guidedMainPlayer" {
//            
//            let playerVC = segue.destination as! playerGuidedViewController

//            playerVC.Day = dayName
//            playerVC.UrlAudio = audioFileURL
//            
//            
//        }
//    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am going to show how to pass the data from the `tablecell` to the `viewcontroller`:
Basically, you have to pass your `viewcontroller` instance to the `tablecell` and then you can access all the properties and method from `viewcontroller` instance in the `tablecell`

```
import UIKit


class backgroundViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var vcInstance: PlayerGuidedTableViewController?
var dayName : String!
var audioFileURL : String!
 var tittle : String?

// guided collectionView
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!


let data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]

let images = ["circleblank","circleblank","circleblank","circleblank","circleblank","circleblank","circleblank"]

@IBOutlet var Labeltittle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var LabelDetail: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var iconview: UIImageView!

 extension backgroundViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell1", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.Label.text = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])

    let bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    var imageView : UIImageView
   imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x :4.1,y : 3.9, width:        cell.ImageView.frame.size.width, height : cell.ImageView.frame.size.height));
    imageView.image = UIImage(named : "blankoval")


    bgColorView.addSubview(imageView)


    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Collection view at row \(collectionView.tag) selected index path \(indexPath.row)")
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:

        dayName = "Day 1"

       self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day1
        break
    case 1:
    self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day2
        dayName = "Day 2"

        break
    case 2:
    self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day3
        dayName = "Day 3"

        break
    case 3:
    self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day4
        dayName = "Day 4"

        break
    case 4:

       self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day5
        dayName = "Day 5"

        break
    case 5:
      self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day6
        dayName = "Day 6"

        break
    default:
        self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day7
        dayName = "Day 7"
        break

    }

 }
vcInstance.dayName = dayName
}
}
```

**You can pass the data from cell to the viewcontroller**

```
import UIKit

class PlayerGuidedTableViewController: UITableViewController {


var audioFileURL : String!
var dayName : String!




// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 600
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> backgroundViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guidedPlayerCell") as! backgroundViewCell
    cell.vcInstance = self
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayerGuidedTableViewController.playPauseButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)


    return cell
}



 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MainPlayer" {
        if let collectionCell: backgroundViewCell = sender as? backgroundViewCell {
            if let collectionView: UICollectionView = collectionCell.superview as? UICollectionView {
                if let playerVC = segue.destination as? playerGuidedViewController {


                    playerVC.Day = dayName
                    playerVC.UrlAudio = audioFileURL
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)    {
//        if segue.identifier == "guidedMainPlayer" {
//            
//            let playerVC = segue.destination as! playerGuidedViewController

//            playerVC.Day = dayName
//            playerVC.UrlAudio = audioFileURL
//            
//            
//        }
//    }
}



}
```

Comment: What are u doing?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in next view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `audioFileURL` and `dayName` variables inside `PlayerGuidedTableViewController` class.

```
class PlayerGuidedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var audioFileURL : String!  //delete this
    var dayName : String!       //delete this
    ...
    ...
}
```

Replace your `prepare(for:sender:)` method with this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MainPlayer" {
        if let backgroundViewCell = sender as? backgroundViewCell {
            if let playerVC = segue.destination as? playerGuidedViewController {
                playerVC.Day = backgroundViewCell.dayName
                playerVC.UrlAudio = backgroundViewCell.audioFileURL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem it generates?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in next view controller.

Comment: On which line of the next view controller your program stops execution?

Comment: This error is occur because data is not passing to next view controller. I printed those var, output is coming nil.

Comment: So this isn't the issue with ___passing data___. This should be issue in the scope where you are filling those variables with values. Must be you are filling some of them with `nil`s. To find out, put print statements everywhere the variables are included.

Comment: I already printed value of url in Nextviewcontroller, output is nil.

Comment: You don't understand what I'm saying? Or aren't you trying to understand? This issue isn't with the ___passing data___. So you won't get anything in the `NextViewController`.

Comment: Try putting print statements in every cases of your switch in `func collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` of `backgroundViewCell` class. Try like this: `case 0:
        dayName = "Day 1"
        self.audioFileURL = musicUrlFile.Day1
        print(self.audioFileURL)
        break`
. And repeat this for each case

Comment: Ya, i printed and data is printing in switch case, but when i put print statement before and after  if let backgroundViewCell = sender as? backgroundViewCell {} statement, inside this block, nothing is printing.